# very odd error in Modelsim vsim.exe and C#

Tags: c#, modelsim

i'm running a command shell VSIM.exe from a software. When I run it through the software (`p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Modeltech_pe_edu_10.2b\win32pe_edu\vsim`, etc...)
I'm getting this error:

```
   Reading C:/modeltech64_10.0d/tcl/vsim/pref.tcl 
couldn't open "transcript": permission denied
Initialization problem, exiting.

    while executing
"BATCHMAIN"
    invoked from within
"if {[batch_mode]} {
    BATCHMAIN
} else {
    GUIMAIN
}"
    invoked from within
"ncFyP12 -+"
    (file "C:\modeltech64_10.0d\win64/../tcl/vsim/vsim" line 1)
** Fatal: Exiting VSIM license process.
```

But, for debug purposes, when I'm running it through cmd.exe, it all works fine!
In CMD I'm running this command:

```
C:\Modeltech_pe_edu_10.2b\win32pe_edu\vsim.exe -c -do d:\script_tcl.tcl
```

in the tcl script I have these lines:

```
cd D:/Packages
set WRK work
if {[file exists $WRK]} {
} else {
vlib work
vmap work work}
vcom abcd.vhd
quit -f
```

so, when running this command from the process.start I'm getting an error regarding the transcript - permission denied, whereas doing the same thing thru a command line- it all works fine!
I've tried that on 4 different versions of ModelSim, all the same thing!!!
Any help will do...
Thank you!

Comment: I dont know much about vlib vmap and vcom are they executables ??? If yes then you need to use with exec keyword to execute binaries in Tcl...

Comment: The 2nd line reads `couldn't open "transcript": permission denied`. Have you checked if you have read access to the file/folder?
If you are calling within another software, check (1) what is the current working dir and (2) if you have write access to it.
Maybe launch this software via `cmd.exe` from a known working dir.